# Get string value out of typescript enum

Tags: typescript, enums

I define a simple enum like so:

```
export enum Type {
    TEST_ONE = "testing.one",
    TEST_TWO = "testing.two",
    BETA = "beta.one"
}
```

Now I want to execute a function for each `enum` string value. Let's say something like this:

```
executeType(type: string) { console.log(type) }

Object.keys(Type).forEach(
    type => {
        executeType(type);
    }
)
```

This outputs the enum values like `TEST_ONE` and `BETA`. How would I go about printing `testing.one` and `beta.one`. I've tried using `type.toString()` and `type.valueOf()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Object.entries(Type).forEach(    
    (entry: [string, string]) => {   
        console.log(entry[1]);    
    }
)
```

Comment: wow thanks! Not sure how I missed "entries". Seems so obvious now that I look at it, as I was iterating over "keys"

Comment: I believe it was easy to miss if you targeted es version less than es2017